# Ansible cloudformation module

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation

I don't understand properly how to use correctly template_parameters parameter (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cloudformation_module.html)

So, looks like I could use this param to override some param in template. Very simple configuration is

**sandbox_cloudformation.yml**

```
---

- name: Sandbox CloudFormation
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

   - name: Launch Ansible CloudFormation Stack
     cloudformation:
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
       stack_name: "{{ aws_default_cloudformation_stack_name }}"
       state: "present"
       region: "{{ aws_default_region }}"
       disable_rollback: true
       template: "files/cloudformation.yml"
     args:
       template_parameters:
         GroupDescription: "Sandbox Security Group"
```

**cloudformation.yml**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Sandbox Stack
Resources:
  SandboxSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "DEMO"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '80'
        ToPort: '80'
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '22'
        ToPort: '22'
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

But I got next error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Parameter values specified for a template which does not require them."}
```

In addition, I got this error, if try to use, for example

```
  template_parameters:
      KeyName: "{{ aws_default_keypair }}"
      InstanceType: "{{ aws_default_instance_type }}"
```

Also, please advice with best approach to use cloudformation module for Ansible. Maybe best way is generate cloud formation template and in the next step use it? Like ..

```
- name: Render Cloud Formation Template
  template: src=cloudformation.yml.j2 dest=rendered_templates/cloudformation.yml

- name: Launch Ansible CloudFormation Stack
         cloudformation:
           template: "rendered_templates/cloudformation.yml"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `template_parameters` to pass parameters to a CloudFormation template. In the template you'll refer to the parameters using `Ref`. In your case:

playbook:

```
...
args:
  template_parameters:
    GroupDescriptionParam: "Sandbox Security Group"
...
```

template:

```
...
Resources:
  SandboxSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription:
        Ref: GroupDescriptionParam
...
```

See 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#w1ab2c19c12d282c19
 for examples of AWS SecurityGroup CloudFormation templates.

Instead of using `template_parameters` arguments in Ansible `cloudformation` module, I have found it handy to create a Jinja2 template, convert it to a CloudFormation template using Ansible `template` module, just like you suggested in the end of your question. Using this approach you can then omit `args` and `template_parameters` in `cloudformation` module call.

For example:

```
- name: Generate CloudFormation template
  become: no
  run_once: yes
  local_action: 
    module: template
    src: "mycloudformation.yml.j2"
    dest: "{{ cf_templ_dir }}/mycloudformation.yml"
  tags:
    - cloudformation
    - cf_template

- name: Deploy the CloudFormation stack
  become: no
  run_once: yes
  local_action: 
    module: cloudformation
    stack_name: "{{ cf_stack_name }}"
    state: present
    region: "{{ ec2_default_region }}"
    template: "{{ cf_templ_dir }}/mycloudformation.yml"
  register: cf_result
  tags:
    - cloudformation

- name: Show CloudFormation output
  run_once: yes
  become: no
  debug: var=cf_result
  tags:
    - cloudformation
```

And mycloudformation.yml.j2:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Sandbox Stack
Resources:
  SandboxSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: {{ group_desc_param_defined_somewhere_in_ansible }}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This extremely useful